# Google PageRank calculation

Tags: seo, google, links, pagerank

I know this might be a stupid question, but I have recently heard, that Google PageRank takes into account links from my sites to big pages, i.e. when I link to big sites, my site get more PageRank. Is that true?

(I am not talking about big sites linking to me)

Comment: Solution: stop caring about PageRank.

Comment: Whatever PR calculation, just think about relevance of links you put on webpages.

Answer (score 1):

Directly answering your question - no, it will not make your PR higher. It is myth.
I can suppose you have heard about it's influence on your site's relevance.
Somebody thoughts that if you place on your website dofollow outbound link to big resource, relevant to yours, it will make Google to think that your site is relevant to this sphere too and make it's trust higher.

Comment: do you happen to have a source?

Comment: @DKOATED just look up the PR algorithm, it only takes into account incoming links, not outgoing links.

Comment: and where is that algorithm published? a google search brings up tons of unconfirmed, speculative sources, except wikipedia, which unfortunately, doesn't say anything about the fact that outgoing links may not be taken into account ...

Comment: PR is increased by age, incoming links, and various site factors such as how often the updates are. I've never heard of PR being increased by linking out... However, Google's algorithm does improve your authority on who you link out too.

Comment: that's my point and assuming authority does have an impact on PR, why should outgoing links not, in some way or another, have a slight impact on PR? That's why I'm looking for a source for @Mirian's claim ...

Comment: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/google1.htm

There You can find three main factors, that make influence on PR.

Comment: @DKOATED Technically, the original algorithm *is* [published](http://pr.efactory.de/e-pagerank-algorithm.shtml). There's just so many other factors Google takes into account that it's largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

**Page Rank** is based on the **Link Analysis Algorithm scale** from 0 to 10 and its depends on the number of backlinks a webpage receiving. A page that is linked to by many pages with high PageRank receives a high rank itself. If there are no links to a web page, then there is no support for that page. In short, If you get backlink from a high PR site then your webpage PR will increase.